# how to find next td > checkbox and weather its checked

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find out how to determine when someone clicks on the `.exempt` checkbox to check if the next `td` `.spammy` checkbox is checked. My code is not working.

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).on('click','.exempt',function() {
    if ($(this).closest('td').next().is('checkbox:checked'), function() {
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<td style="text-align: center; width: 20px; " class=""><input type="checkbox" class="exempt" name="exempt" id="3887"></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 20px; " class=""><input type="checkbox" class="spammy" name="spammy" id="3887"></td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next element after a `td` cannot be a `checkbox:checked`, because it is by definition a `td` element. The syntax of your `if` statement is also off.

You probably meant:

```
if ($(this).closest('td').next().find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) {
    // Do something
}
```

or

```
if ($(this).closest('td').next().find('input[type=checkbox]').is(":checked")) {
    // Do something
}
```

**Live Example:**

```js
$(document).on('click', '.exempt', function() {
  if ($(this).closest('td').next().find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length) {
    alert("yes, it's checked");
  } else {
    alert("no, it isn't");
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center; width: 20px; " class="">
        <input type="checkbox" class="exempt" name="exempt">
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center; width: 20px; " class="">
        <input type="checkbox" class="spammy" name="spammy">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center; width: 20px; " class="">
        <input type="checkbox" class="exempt" name="exempt">
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center; width: 20px; " class="">
        <input type="checkbox" class="spammy" name="spammy" checked>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Separately: You have two elements with the same `id` value. That's invalid HTML, `id` values **must** be unique in the document.